# WPF : Get column header from a specific cell

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid in which I create dynamically columns depending of the several criterion (date and department). Each of the column is actually a listbox which will contains item to drag around.

My problem here is that each listbox items source differs. The only way I can see how I can find the source if by reading the header ( I wanted to add some sort of parameter to my column and cell, but I just can't find it.

Is there any way to do that ?

Regards,

Comment: You should show the code you are using so far to help people help you

Answer (score 1):

you can have your xaml as

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Field1CellTemplate" >
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DeptCellTemplate" >
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Field1" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource Field1CellTemplate}" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Field1}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Dept" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource DeptCellTemplate}" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dept}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn >

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And you have set the itemssource of each column data dynamically as

```
DataTemplate Field1CellTemplate = this.TryFindResource("Field1CellTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        if (Field1CellTemplate != null)
        {
            var frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
            frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new object[] { "option1", "option2", "option3" });
            Field1CellTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
        }

        DataTemplate DeptCellTemplate = this.TryFindResource("DeptCellTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        if (Field1CellTemplate != null)
        {
            var frameworkElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
            frameworkElementFactory.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new object[] { "CS", "ETC", "IT" });
            DeptCellTemplate.VisualTree = frameworkElementFactory;
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Field1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Dept");
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "option1", "CS"});
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "option3", "IT" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "option2", "ETC" });

        grid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was simple enough

```
 Dim oLstBox As ListBox = e.Source
 Dim poste As T_Ref_Poste = oLstBox.DataContext
 Dim row = dgHoraire.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(poste)
```